# Which library to link to user boost::intrusive_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, linker, shared-libraries

is there possibility to find out which library file to link for libs that are using boost::intrusive_ptr?

I tried to use the boost bcp tool, but that does not give any hint in which dylib boost::intrusive_ptr is compiled.

On my system, I have these boost libs compiled (Version 1.49.0):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/lib/
libboost_chrono-mt.a            libboost_iostreams-mt.a         libboost_math_c99l-mt.dylib     libboost_program_options-mt.a       libboost_serialization-mt.dylib     libboost_timer-mt.dylib
libboost_chrono-mt.dylib        libboost_iostreams-mt.dylib     libboost_math_tr1-mt.a          libboost_program_options-mt.dylib   libboost_signals-mt.a           libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.a
libboost_date_time-mt.a         libboost_locale-mt.a            libboost_math_tr1-mt.dylib      libboost_python-mt.a            libboost_signals-mt.dylib       libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib
libboost_date_time-mt.dylib     libboost_locale-mt.dylib        libboost_math_tr1f-mt.a         libboost_python-mt.dylib        libboost_system-mt.a            libboost_wave-mt.a
libboost_exception-mt.a         libboost_math_c99-mt.a          libboost_math_tr1f-mt.dylib     libboost_random-mt.a            libboost_system-mt.dylib        libboost_wave-mt.dylib
libboost_filesystem-mt.a        libboost_math_c99-mt.dylib      libboost_math_tr1l-mt.a         libboost_random-mt.dylib        libboost_test_exec_monitor-mt.a     libboost_wserialization-mt.a
libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib        libboost_math_c99f-mt.a         libboost_math_tr1l-mt.dylib     libboost_regex-mt.a         libboost_thread-mt.a            libboost_wserialization-mt.dylib
libboost_graph-mt.a         libboost_math_c99f-mt.dylib     libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.a      libboost_regex-mt.dylib         libboost_thread-mt.dylib
libboost_graph-mt.dylib         libboost_math_c99l-mt.a         libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.dylib  libboost_serialization-mt.a     libboost_timer-mt.a
```

The lib names themselves do not always give a hint to find the file to be linked (e.g boost::asio is in lboost_system-mt). Obviously it cannot be senseful to link randomly. Is there any way to find dependencies if I use anything from boost?

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: `intrusive_ptr` is header only. There's no library needed to link with.

Comment: The header file of the lib that I want to compile looks like the following:

#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>

I am linking lboost_thread-mt but still get the linker error for undefined symbols

Comment: @SebastianB. that has nothing to do with `intrusive_ptr`. Which symbols are you missing? BTW it might be worth changing the question or posting a new one.

Comment: Yep, I did post a new question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212328/link-phase-with-recursive-makefile-fails-with-undefined-symbols-using-boostint

Answer (score 2):

`intrusive_ptr` is a part of Smart Pointers library, which is header-only, i.e. you don't need to link anything.

Boost.Asio is not *in* lboost_system-mt, it just *uses* Boost.System (which is documented).